# Applying Rotation and Scale Deforms my object

Tags: edit-mode

Hi i'm just a newbie here in blender. I'm trying apply rotation and scale to the object but it just deforms. How to fix this problem?

Thanks!

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Remove its keyframes first.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!